# Automatic vector boundary checking without crashing my program

Tags: c++, vector, chess

I am creating a working chess game

My chess engine has a board. The board is a 2D board[Y][X], and the within it are Pieces. Pieces are enums, and it represents black pieces, white pieces, and NONE.

```
class ChessBoard
{
   vector<vector<Piece>> board(); //I made it 8*8 in the constructor
   enum Piece{NONE, white pieces, black pieces etc..}
}
```

My problem is validating if a square is within my board. Please let me elaborate. For example, when looking at the possible moves for A2 pawn, the pawn can either move up 1 2 or capture left right, or en passant left right:

```
(X,Y+1), (X,Y+2), (X+1,Y+1), (X-1,Y+1), (X+1,Y+2), (X-1,Y-2)
```

However, as you know, X-1 will cause the piece to go out of bounds.

Yes, I could implement a simple bool `isSquareValid()` function. But this means, where ever I am trying to access or set `board[][]`, i need to call this function.

Is there a way to implement Board[][] so that when I am trying to access out of bound indexes, it will throw an error message or something without crashing my program?

Thanks

Comment: There is no way to implement an `operator[][]`, except using two `operator[]` in tandem.    `std::vector` provides an `at()` member function which checks for valid indices, but it is necessary to catch exceptions to prevent program termination.    Note that `vector<vector<Piece>> board(8*8)` specifies a `vector` containing 64 `vector<Piece>`, each of which has no elements.   It doesn't create an 8x8 array in any form.

Comment: Of course, in chess, a pawn can't move through other pieces, even if the destination square is on the board.

Comment: Yes I know, I kinda wrote psuedo code just to show that board was 8*8... Anyways, I really dont want to do if(isValidSquare(x,y)) EVERYTIME i try to look at or access the board.... Is there a smart way to do this? I thought maybe making it a 10*10 board with the outer layer as ERROR might help.

Comment: That part is easy to check, I only move the pawn if board[y][x] == NONE, or if it can capture.

Comment: Just write your code (e.g. for a single move) using vector's `at()` instead of `[]` syntax, as if the array indices are correct.   Then wrap that in a try/catch block.   If any of the indices are invalid, an exception will be thrown.

Comment: What do you want to happen if an error is detected? Throwing an exception is fine, but what do you to handle it?

Comment: @n.m Ideally, if I shouldn't be trying to access an out of bound index...

Comment: @Peter, that does not sound like a good way of solving this problem. if i have to wrap everything in try catch... I'd rather just check for boundary with my isValidSquare function.

Comment: So is your goal to print an error message and exit?

Comment: You don't wrap each array access in an individual try/catch, you wrap your entire game engine in a single try/catch.

Comment: You don't want to check for invalid array indices, but somehow you want to prevent use of invalid array indices (which, frankly, I view as a poor requirement, but that's what you specified).    That limits your options a fair bit.   `vector.at()` provides such a facility, but communicates via exceptions when an invalid index is used.   As n.m said, that does not mean wrapping every operation in try/catch .... work out a way to centralise the handling.

Comment: What is the user interface for the game? Perhaps it would be easier to block access there also giving the user an earlier indication that the move is illegal.

Comment: Put a border (edge) on your board so the chess board is 10x10 with the edge squares set to the value `border` (instead of `empty`, `black-pawn` etc).  Out of bounds testing is then simply for example, `board[x+1][y-1] == boarder`

Comment: @Richard Critten. Yes I think that is a feasible method, however, I still have to do if(board[y][x]!=boarder) everytime...

Comment: @o_weisman, command line at the moment. User gets to enter moves like E2-E4, and my program will look for all valid moves and check if E2-E4 is one of them. That is the problem, I am not sure how to "block" access...

Comment: @Peter, No I really dont like that method, I find it really ugly to read... Imagine I have to use board.at(3)[4] everywhere... =/ I also dont want to use try catch because I think doing isValidSquare() or using a 10*10 is better.

Comment: @weixinzeng You never have to test against `border` because:   If the square is not `empty` it must be a piece or `border`.  If it is a piece generate a capture or illegal move (if it's occupied by one of your pieces) ELSE it must be a `border` square and the move is illegal.  In summary, if square is empty - generate move; their piece - capture; my piece - illegal move; else illegal move

Comment: @Richard Critten Yes i really like that solution too. My board can then be accessed using 1-8 instead of 0-7, which is nice... Thanks.

Comment: @RichardCritten Wouldn't that be a 12x12 array, due to the movement of the knight?

Comment: @HerbWolfe you are right, was thinking about other board games

Comment: Thanks for your inputs everyone. I have decided to go with adding a wrapper class around my board and overload the () operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up two different problems.

The first is how to make sure that the game prevents a piece from ending up outside the board. This is *not* error handling; you must make sure that the piece never ends up there in the first place. In other words, you must restrict the program logic to valid moves **before a choice is even presented to the user** (or to an AI component, for that matter). If you fancy the idea of catching the exception thrown from `at` and then reverting the board to a valid state, stop right there and don't do that. It would be exception abuse at its finest.

The second is how to handle an error resulting from a bug in your code. You may have written code to prevent the game from putting pieces outside of the board, but you may have made a mistake, because we all do, so you do end up with illegal vector indices after all. In this case, the crash resulting from `operator[]` is actually a good thing, because immediate termination of a buggy program is usually the best thing that can happen to you. The alternative is to "somehow continue" and go on with corrupted data and broken game rules, perhaps not even noticing the bug quickly enough.

Because it's not guaranteed that a wrong `operator[]` call causes a crash, and forcing the runtime library to perform the checks can be a bit cumbersome (a wrong `operator[]` index is formally undefined behaviour, of course), you might want to add some `assert` statements of your own and make sure that `NDEBUG` does not prevent them from doing their job.

This gets considerably easier if you wrap the `std::vector` in a class of your own. While you're at it, you can then simplify element access with `operator()`:

```
class Board
{
public:
    Piece& operator()(int x, int y)
    {
        assert(x >= 0);
        assert(x < 16);
        assert(y >= 0);
        assert(y < 16);
        return data[y][x];
    }

    Piece operator()(int x, int y) const
    {
        assert(x >= 0);
        assert(x < 16);
        assert(y >= 0);
        assert(y < 16);
        return data[y][x];
    }

    Board()
    {
        for (int row_index = 0; row_index < 16; ++row_index)
        {
            data.emplace_back(16, Piece::None);
        }
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::vector<Piece>> data;
};
```

Also note that `std::vector` is a poor choice for a chess board, because chess boards do not shrink or grow. Consider using `std::array` instead.

Comment: Ok, so when I try to access a board position i just do if(board(x,y)).. I really like this solution...